# How to use createElement() function in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I want to create an element in XML file using CodeIgniter, but every time I'm getting a fatal error: "Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::createElement()". Here is my code in Controller, View & Model  class, what am I doing wrong?

**Controller (xml_insert.php):**

```
    <?php

class Xml_insert extends CI_Controller {

function index() {

    $this->load->model('xml_insert_model');
    $data['rows'] = $this->xml_insert_model->getAll();
    $this->load->view('xml_insert_view', $data);
}

function insert() {
    $this->load->model('xml_insert_model');
    $data['rows'] = $this->xml_insert_model->getAll();

    foreach ($data['rows'] as $r) {
        $path1 = $r->xml_file_path;
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($path1);

        $newAct = $_POST['activity'];

        $root = $xml->firstChild;

        $newElement = $xml->createElement('activity');
        $root->appendChild($newElement);
        $newText = $xml->createTextNode($newAct);
        $newElement->appendChild($newText);

        $xml->save('$path1');
        $this->index();
    }
}

}
```

**View (xml_insert_view.php):**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   <?php foreach ($rows as $r): ?>
    <?php
            $path1 = $r->xml_file_path;
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($path1);
    ?>
    <?php  foreach ($xml->children() as $activity) : ?>
    <?php echo "Activity : " . $activity . " <br />"; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>

      <form name="input" action="index.php/xml_insert/insert" method="post">
      insert activity:
      <input type="text" name="activity"/>
      <input type="submit" value="send"/>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Model (xml_insert_model.php):**

```
    <?php
    class Xml_insert_model extends CI_Model
    {
      function getAll()
      {

         $q = $this->db->get("XML");

         if ($q->num_rows > 0) {

           foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
              $data[] = $row;
           }

          return $data;
         }
      }
   }
```

**XML file(sample.xml)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <list>
      <activity>swimming</activity>
      <activity>running</activity>
      <activity>Jogging</activity>
      <activity>Theatre</activity>
      <activity>Programming</activity>
  <activity>driving</activity>
  <activity>eating</activity>
    </list>
```

Comment: You'll want to define your specific issue further. Pasting all code won't get you much support.  And my first thought, based on intro and no need to look at code, is Are you sure that function createElement is available to you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use functions of `DomDocument`

instead of

`$xml = simplexml_load_file($path1);`

Try

```
$xml = new DomDocument();
$xml->load($path1);
```

You can use `addChild` method of `simpleXML` if you prefer.